# Why is this difference in INSERT performance...?

Tags: mysql, performance, insert

Hi recently I conducted a test on two different ubuntu servers.

```
    Here are the results:
    innodb_flush_trx_commit = 1
    Staging Server: 10,000 Inserts ----> 81 seconds  
    innodb_flush_trx_commit = 2 
    Staging Server: 10,000 Inserts ----> 61 seconds  

    Dev     Server: 
    innodb_flush_trx_commit = 1
    10,000 Inserts ----> 5 seconds  
    Dev     Server: 
    innodb_flush_trx_commit = 2
    10,000 Inserts ---->  2 seconds 

    I am clear that performance vary with innodb_flush setting.
    But why there is a huge diff in performance from the server to server ?
```

What are the things to consider here...?
Here are the some of the details considered but no significant thing to suspect:

```
    staging server: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU X5355 @2.66GHz
                    processor 0, 1  
                    mysql 5.1.61
                    innodb_buffer_pool : 8MB
                    RAM: 4GB                        

    dev     server: AMD Opteron(tm) Processor 4130 @2.60ghZ
                    processor 0, 1  
                    mysql 5.0.67
                    innodb_buffer_pool : 8MB
                    RAM: 4GB
```

Please help in understanding what is the exact thing that has lead to this huge difference in perfromance on different servers...?

```
  NOTE: same script used in the same way on noth the servers and not from remote  
        sesrvers.
```

Thanks in advance.
Regards,
UDAY

Comment: So you're wondering how come that one computer saves data to its hard drive quicker than another without telling us what the HDD subsystem being used is on either of them?

Comment: No  NB.... Not like that. I am just not sure on what are the things to consider to find out this behavior.

Comment: shall you publihs how can i check to know the details about HDD sub system please...?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but shouldn't you have information about server hardware before you buy it? `sudo hdparm -I /dev/sda` should give you enough info about hdd subsystem.

Comment: NB, it seems this is the problem with the binary logging enabled on the server. To be frnak we have but they are not accessible to me. this can happen right...?

Comment: Binary logging just indicates there's extra HDD activity at one of the servers. What is probably the case here is that one of your servers simply has faster HDD subsystem. If you want to compare performance on two servers, you must do it in the same conditions, on the same hardware, using the same software. Otherwise it's just meaningless and you can't wonder how come 1 server pushes that many inserts and the other one doesn't. Also, 10k inserts in 2 seconds is quite a bit. Is that Amazon EBS volume being used?

Comment: NB, You are right. But we cant always come to this state where both the servers are in exact state interms of h/w, s/w and the rest. This is common where we have to dig in performance variations across 2 or more similar servers. unfortunately i am part of one such situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some questions I'd go through...

Is binary logging turned on with one instance and not the other?

Is the staging server using a networked drive to access the mysql data?

Is the filesystem type the same on both servers (ext3, ext2, etc.)?

Disk activity seems to be the culprit here.

Comment: file system is same for the both [ext3].  You are right david.... you are right.... binary logging is enabled on staging. Its great your input david. I am pleased with it.... thanq so much.

Comment: David.... Is it the only reason. enabling binary logging will make such a huge impact on the performance...? I am really wondered with this. anyways I will test this. How can i stop the binary logging on the fly...? is there any way to do so without stopping the server..>?

Comment: The only way to stop binary logging is to edit the my.cnf file and then restart mysql.

Answer (score 1):

Is you staging server a production server? In that case it is probably a concurrency issue. If many users are working on that server, inserts may be slower, especially if the table(s) you are inserting into are being used by others too. 
The dev server probably has much less load, with only a few developers using it simultaneously.

Comment: Ya.... concurrency would matter. But here both the servers are idle nothing like that to suspect. anyways thanks for the reply Golez....

Answer (score 1):

Keeping the hard ware differences aside (which is not a easy assumption). The factors that influence a query performance are:

1. Version of the DBMS engine
2. Query plan and db statistics used
3. Network latency
4. Memory allocated to the DBMS engine (Transaction buffer log included)
5. Process/thread priority of the DBMS engine

Comment: versions I presented.                                                Its just a simple insert into an empty table.                         network latency doesnt matter as the insert is from the same server to the same server. memory allocations are same. I am not sure onthe 5th point questzen... thanks for rising these points.

Comment: Ideal way to do bench marks is to use the same environment and eco-system. It is less than ideal to do otherwise. In real world, we still do this, to find out if the statistics are acceptable or not. It is not a trivial task to figure out the exact differentiators in scenarios such as yours.

Comment: Hi questzen.. binary logging is enabled on the staging server. this is why such a huge performance degrade i guess. anyways i will test this with out binary logging enabled. thanks for your time and feeds.

Answer (score 1):

I also would suggest to check the disk utilization. To get a raw idea how your disk utilization performs while you are running your test you could use `iostat` (on redhat based systems it is in the package `systat`)

For example you could try the following:

iostat -xd 1

which would lead to an output simmilar to this:

```
Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s   rsec/s   wsec/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await  svctm  %util
sda               0.00     0.31    0.00    0.05     0.16     2.89    56.67     0.00    2.99   0.62   0.00
```

Compare here the `await` time on both machines. This metric shows you the average time in milliseconds which the disk needs to serve I/O requests. Its a quick way to check if there are big differences. Also interesting could be the `%util` metric. This one gives you the percentage of cpu time which is spent while issuing I/O operations to the device, as higher this value gets, as closer you get to the full saturation of your device.

For the other options check `man iostat`.

Of course above described only gives you a very basic overview of how your disks perform. So keep this in mind as an additional operation to the previous mentioned one in order to track down your problem.